# Traversing Next and Previous jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have an odd design which has then been coded as:

```
<div class="white-wrap row people-grid">
   <ul class="people-list  row">
      <li class="person row">
         <div class="inner row">
            <div class="image"> <img src="images/peterHarthill.png" alt="peterHarthill" width="240" height="226"> </div>
            <div class="info"> <span class="name"><span>Peter</span> <span>Hartill</span></span> <span class="role">Chairman</span> <a class="selected expand-person" href="#pete1">Toggle more</a> </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="person row">
         <div class="inner row">
            <div class="image"> <img src="images/peterHarthill.png" alt="peterHarthill" width="240" height="226"> </div>
            <div class="info"> <span class="name"><span>Peter</span> <span>Hartill</span></span> <span class="role">Chairman</span> <a  class="expand-person" href="#pete2">Toggle more</a> </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="person row">
         <div class="inner row">
            <div class="image"> <img src="images/peterHarthill.png" alt="peterHarthill" width="240" height="226"> </div>
            <div class="info"> <span class="name"><span>Peter</span> <span>Hartill</span></span> <span class="role">Chairman</span> <a  class="expand-person" href="#pete3">Toggle more</a> </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="expanded ">
      <li class="tab active" id="pete1">
         <article class="expand row">
            <div class="info">
               <h1>Perter Hartill</h1>
               <h2>Chairman</h2>
               <p>Peter was a Senior Audit Partner with Deloitte, based in their Birmingham office, having retired on 31st May 2008.  Peter was with Deloitte for over 40 years based mainly in the Midlands but also spent time at their offices in London and Washington US.  During his career he acted for most of Deloitte's major Midlands clients and one of his specialist areas was the real estate sector.
                  Peter became Chairman of Deeley on 1st January 2009.
                  Peter is married with 2 step-children and enjoys golf and other sports. 
               </p>
            </div>
            <aside>
               <ul class="qualifications">
                  <li><strong>Qualifications</strong> Chartered Accountant</li>
                  <li><strong>Professional Affiliations</strong> FCA</li>
                  <li><strong>Start Date</strong> September 1988</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="share row">
                  <h2>Share</h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </article>
         <span class="collapse-btn">collapse</span> <span class="collapse-next-btn">next</span> <span class="collapse-prev-btn">prev</span> 
      </li>
      <li  class="tab" id="pete2">
         <article class="expand row">
            <div class="info">
               <h1>Perter Hartill</h1>
               <h2>Chairman</h2>
               <p>Peter was a Senior Audit Partner with Deloitte, based in their Birmingham office, having retired on 31st May 2008.  Peter was with Deloitte for over 40 years based mainly in the Midlands but also spent time at their offices in London and Washington US.  During his career he acted for most of Deloitte's major Midlands clients and one of his specialist areas was the real estate sector.
                  Peter became Chairman of Deeley on 1st January 2009.
                  Peter is married with 2 step-children and enjoys golf and other sports. 
               </p>
            </div>
            <aside>
               <ul class="qualifications">
                  <li><strong>Qualifications</strong> Chartered Accountant</li>
                  <li><strong>Professional Affiliations</strong> FCA</li>
                  <li><strong>Start Date</strong> September 1988</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="share row">
                  <h2>Share</h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </article>
         <span class="collapse-btn">collapse</span> <span class="collapse-next-btn">next</span> <span class="collapse-prev-btn">prev</span> 
      </li>
      <li  class="tab" id="pete3">
         <article class="expand row">
            <div class="info">
               <h1>Perter Hartill</h1>
               <h2>Chairman</h2>
               <p>Peter was a Senior Audit Partner with Deloitte, based in their Birmingham office, having retired on 31st May 2008.  Peter was with Deloitte for over 40 years based mainly in the Midlands but also spent time at their offices in London and Washington US.  During his career he acted for most of Deloitte's major Midlands clients and one of his specialist areas was the real estate sector.
                  Peter became Chairman of Deeley on 1st January 2009.
                  Peter is married with 2 step-children and enjoys golf and other sports. 
               </p>
            </div>
            <aside>
               <ul class="qualifications">
                  <li><strong>Qualifications</strong> Chartered Accountant</li>
                  <li><strong>Professional Affiliations</strong> FCA</li>
                  <li><strong>Start Date</strong> September 1988</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="share row">
                  <h2>Share</h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </article>
         <span class="collapse-btn">collapse</span> <span class="collapse-next-btn">next</span> <span class="collapse-prev-btn">prev</span> 
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="people-list row">
      <li class="person row">
         <div class="inner row">
            <div class="image"> <img src="images/peterHarthill.png" alt="peterHarthill" width="240" height="226"> </div>
            <div class="info"> <span class="name"><span>Peter</span> <span>Hartill</span></span> <span class="role">Chairman</span> <a data-content="inbox" class="expand-person" href="#pete4">Toggle more</a> </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="person row">
         <div class="inner row">
            <div class="image"> <img src="images/peterHarthill.png" alt="peterHarthill" width="240" height="226"> </div>
            <div class="info"> <span class="name"><span>Peter</span> <span>Hartill</span></span> <span class="role">Chairman</span> <a data-content="peter" class="expand-person" href="#pete5">Toggle more</a> </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="person row">
         <div class="inner row">
            <div class="image"> <img src="images/peterHarthill.png" alt="peterHarthill" width="240" height="226"> </div>
            <div class="info"> <span class="name"><span>Peter</span> <span>Hartill</span></span> <span class="role">Chairman</span> <a data-content="peter" class="expand-person" href="#pete6">Toggle more</a> </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="expanded cd-tabs-content">
      <li  class="tab" id="pete4">
         <article class="expand row">
            <div class="info">
               <h1>Perter Hartill</h1>
               <h2>Chairman</h2>
               <p>Peter was a Senior Audit Partner with Deloitte, based in their Birmingham office, having retired on 31st May 2008.  Peter was with Deloitte for over 40 years based mainly in the Midlands but also spent time at their offices in London and Washington US.  During his career he acted for most of Deloitte's major Midlands clients and one of his specialist areas was the real estate sector.
                  Peter became Chairman of Deeley on 1st January 2009.
                  Peter is married with 2 step-children and enjoys golf and other sports. 
               </p>
            </div>
            <aside>
               <ul class="qualifications">
                  <li><strong>Qualifications</strong> Chartered Accountant</li>
                  <li><strong>Professional Affiliations</strong> FCA</li>
                  <li><strong>Start Date</strong> September 1988</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="share row">
                  <h2>Share</h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </article>
         <span class="collapse-btn">collapse</span> <span class="collapse-next-btn">next</span> <span class="collapse-prev-btn">prev</span> 
      </li>
      <li  class="tab" id="pete5">
         <article class="expand row">
            <div class="info">
               <h1>Perter Hartill</h1>
               <h2>Chairman</h2>
               <p>Peter was a Senior Audit Partner with Deloitte, based in their Birmingham office, having retired on 31st May 2008.  Peter was with Deloitte for over 40 years based mainly in the Midlands but also spent time at their offices in London and Washington US.  During his career he acted for most of Deloitte's major Midlands clients and one of his specialist areas was the real estate sector.
                  Peter became Chairman of Deeley on 1st January 2009.
                  Peter is married with 2 step-children and enjoys golf and other sports. 
               </p>
            </div>
            <aside>
               <ul class="qualifications">
                  <li><strong>Qualifications</strong> Chartered Accountant</li>
                  <li><strong>Professional Affiliations</strong> FCA</li>
                  <li><strong>Start Date</strong> September 1988</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="share row">
                  <h2>Share</h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </article>
      </li>
      <li  class="tab" id="pete6">
         <article class="expand row">
            <div class="info">
               <h1>Perter Hartill</h1>
               <h2>Chairman</h2>
               <p>Peter was a Senior Audit Partner with Deloitte, based in their Birmingham office, having retired on 31st May 2008.  Peter was with Deloitte for over 40 years based mainly in the Midlands but also spent time at their offices in London and Washington US.  During his career he acted for most of Deloitte's major Midlands clients and one of his specialist areas was the real estate sector.
                  Peter became Chairman of Deeley on 1st January 2009.
                  Peter is married with 2 step-children and enjoys golf and other sports. 
               </p>
            </div>
            <aside>
               <ul class="qualifications">
                  <li><strong>Qualifications</strong> Chartered Accountant</li>
                  <li><strong>Professional Affiliations</strong> FCA</li>
                  <li><strong>Start Date</strong> September 1988</li>
               </ul>
               <div class="share row">
                  <h2>Share</h2>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                     <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </article>
         <span class="collapse-btn">collapse</span> <span class="collapse-next-btn">next</span> <span class="collapse-prev-btn">prev</span> 
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Current jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.people-grid a').on('click', function(e){
      var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      jQuery('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      jQuery(this).addClass('selected');

      // Show/Hide Tabs
      jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
      jQuery('.people-grid ' + currentAttrValue).addClass('active');        
      e.preventDefault();
   });

   jQuery('.collapse-next-btn').on('click', function(e){        
      jQuery('.active').removeClass('active'); 
      jQuery(this).parent('.tab').next().addClass('active');
   });  
});
```

It's basically a tab set up, but because of the way it is designed they have to be split up.

I need the next and previous buttons to remove the active class from the current li.tab and add it to the next one. I can do it within the same ul, but can't choose the next/previous li of the next ul.expanded when it reaches the end/start of the current list.

I also need to then highlight the corresponding button with "selected"

The dev site can be seen at http://deeley.devmode.co.uk/people.html as i'm sure I probably haven't made much sense!

If Anyone can lend a hand as i've been going round in circles all day!

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got the code done for you because your `a.expand-person` elements do what you need.

The next and previous arrows just need to find the next `a.expand-person` and trigger the click on that element.